# Client CA certificate & RADIUS

Tags: certificate-authority, client-side, radius

when my client tries to authenticate with Radius servers it gives following error:
*unable to get local issuer certificate*

As per my understanding, this is a trust chain problem or, in other words, my client is missing the CA certificate.

Which exactly certificate do I need to install on the client? Radius has two certificate chains (one for identyfing itself, and one for communication with clients) + private key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what authentication method you'll be using, but generally speaking:

The RADIUS Server needs:

- The CA certificate that it will be using to verify certificates it sees
- It's own server certificate & corresponding private key

The Client needs:

- The CA certificate that it will be using to verify certificates it sees
- (depending on authentication method) It's own client certificate & corresponding private key

Assuming you're using EAP-TLS, when a client connects to the server, there is the initial TLS handshake which basically starts off like this:

1. Client sends its own cert to server
2. Server validates that cert using the CA cert
3. If good, Server responds, showing the client its server cert
4. Client validates that cert using the CA cert
5. ...
6. ...

If you're using another authentication method, client certs are generally not needed, but the client will still need a CA cert that can be used to validate the server cert that is shown to it.

Comment: Travelyam  CA cert on clients would be the same root and intermediate that reside on the server?

Comment: Generally yea, I can't really think of a strong use case that would require them to be different, but the important thing is the purpose. The client uses the CA cert to validate the server's identity when it receives the server cert, so the server cert will need to have been signed by this root or intermediate CA in the CA cert on the client. The server does the same procedure to validate the client's identity - so the client cert will need to have been signed by the root/intermediate in the CA cert on the server. In every case I've seen myself, the CA cert on the client & server are the same.